# Shuffle symbol breaks footnotes?

Tags: fonts, symbols

I am currently recompiling a draft monograph with Springer's "svmono" class. When compiling the file, everything seems to work fine, but the first time TeX encounters a footnote, it throws the error message

```
! LaTeX Error: Font U/shuffle/m/n/4.25 not found.
```

Here is a minimal example generating the error:

```
\documentclass{svmono}
\usepackage{shuffle}

\begin{document}
This is a footnote.
\footnote{This generates an error message.}
\end{document}
```

If the "footnote" line is commmented out, it works fine. In case anyone wants to try, here is a Dropbox link to the svmono class: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2623632/svmono.cls. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

While I need the shuffle symbol in the main text, I don't ever need it inside a footnote, so I would be happy with a solution that fixes the error message at the expense of breaking the \shuffle command inside the \footnote command. In case it helps, I am using TeX Live 2013 on OS X. Thank you very much in advance for any hints!

Comment: the `shuffle` font is defined in the package only from size 5pt; for whatever reason, `svmono` seems to want a smaller size.  but why it should hang up without even trying to set the symbol is a mystery to me.  there's also questionable code in `shuffle.sty` -- the symbols are given hex locations of `"001` and `"002`, whereas i would expect `"01` and `"02` -- but i don't think that would cause this sort of problem.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The math sizes defined by `svmono` are nonstandard.

Here's a way out

```
\documentclass{svmono}
\usepackage{fix-cm} % avoid tons of warnings
\usepackage{shuffle}
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{shuffle}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{shuffle}{m}{n}{ <-8>shuffle7 <8->shuffle10}{}

\begin{document}
This is a footnote.
\footnote{This generates an error message.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

Quick fix.

Redefine `\footnotesize` not be the same as `\small` as defined in `svmono.sty`, but to be:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnotesize{%
   \@setfontsize\footnotesize{8}{10}%
   \abovedisplayskip 8.5\p@ % \@plus3\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ %\@plus2\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ %\@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \parsep \z@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \topsep 6\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
               \itemsep\z@}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{svmono}
\usepackage{shuffle}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\footnotesize{%
   \@setfontsize\footnotesize{8}{10}%
   \abovedisplayskip 8.5\p@ % \@plus3\p@ \@minus4\p@
   \abovedisplayshortskip \z@ %\@plus2\p@
   \belowdisplayshortskip 4\p@ %\@plus2\p@ \@minus2\p@
   \def\@listi{\leftmargin\leftmargini
               \parsep \z@ \@plus\p@ \@minus\p@
               \topsep 6\p@ \@plus2\p@ \@minus4\p@
               \itemsep\z@}%
   \belowdisplayskip \abovedisplayskip
}

\begin{document}
This is a footnote.
\footnote{This doesn't generates an error message.}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Another method is to overwrite the definitions contained in `Ushuffle.fd`, that is add the following lines in the preamble:

```
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{shuffle}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{shuffle}{m}{n}{%
<4-8>shuffle7%
<8->shuffle10%
}{}
```

MWE (the result is the same as above):

```
\documentclass{svmono}
\usepackage{shuffle}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{shuffle}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{shuffle}{m}{n}{%
<4-8>shuffle7%
<8->shuffle10%
}{}

\begin{document}
This is a footnote.
\footnote{This doesn't generates an error message.}
\end{document}
```