# Latex Math Symbol

Tags: symbols

Could anyone tell me what is the command for this math symbol in LaTeX Math mode?

[image: Symbol]

Comment: It could be a rotated `\exists`.

Comment: Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This combines two `\sqcup`s and uses `\mathchoice` so that it sets in any mathstyle.

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\dsqcup{\sqcup\mathchoice{\mkern-7mu}{\mkern-7mu}{\mkern-3.2mu}{\mkern-3.8mu}\sqcup}
\begin{document}
$A \dsqcup B$

$\scriptstyle A \dsqcup B$

$\scriptscriptstyle A \dsqcup B$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That's awesome!

Comment: This is awesome !

Answer (score 20):

The symbol is available in Unicode: U+29E2 Shuffle product

### LuaTeX/XeTeX

- Asana Math:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}  
  \usepackage{unicode-math}   
  \setmathfont{Asana-Math.otf}
  \begin{document}
  \[A \shuffle B\]
  \end{document}
  ```

  > [image: Asana Math]
- XITS Math

  ```
  \setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
  ```

  > [image: XITS Math]
- Not available in

  - Latin Modern Math
  - TeX Gyre Math fonts

### Metafont

- Package `shuffle`:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{shuffle}
  \begin{document}
  \[A \shuffle B\]
  \end{document}
  ```

  > [image: shuffle]

  Or with support of any sizes (especially < 5pt, see [Shuffle symbol breaks footnotes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166276/shuffle-symbol-breaks-footnotes)):

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \DeclareSymbolFont{Shuffle}{U}{shuffle}{m}{n}
  \DeclareFontFamily{U}{shuffle}{}
  \DeclareFontShape{U}{shuffle}{m}{n}{%
    <-8>shuffle7%
    <8->shuffle10%
  }{}
  \DeclareMathSymbol\shuffle{\mathbin}{Shuffle}{"001}
  \DeclareMathSymbol\cshuffle{\mathbin}{Shuffle}{"002}

  \begin{document}
  \[ A \shuffle B \]
  \end{document}
  ```

### Symbol composition with rules

Packages are not needed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\shuffle}{%
  \mathbin{\mathpalette\shuffle@{}}%
}
\newcommand*{\shuffle@}[2]{%
  % #1: math style
  % #2: unused
  \sbox0{$#1\vcenter{}$}%
  \kern .15\ht0 % side bearing
  \rlap{\vrule height .25\ht0 depth 0pt width 2.5\ht0}%
  \raise.1\ht0\hbox to 2.5\ht0{%
    \vrule height 1.75\ht0 depth -.1\ht0 width .17\ht0 %
    \hfill
    \vrule height 1.75\ht0 depth -.1\ht0 width .17\ht0 %
    \hfill
    \vrule height 1.75\ht0 depth -.1\ht0 width .17\ht0 %
  }%
  \kern .15\ht0 % side bearing
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[
  A \shuffle B_{A \shuffle B_{A \shuffle B}}
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: rules]

Comment: See also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/166276/shuffle-symbol-breaks-footnotes for solving an issue involving the `shuffle` package

Comment: You beat Detexify on that one. It could not recognize it.

Answer (score 2):

`\shuffle` is defined in the `stix` package.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative `l3draw` solution:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{l3draw,xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
%---------------------------------------------------------
\fp_new:N \l__expl_shuffle_fp

\cs_new_protected:Nn \expl_shuffle:
 {
  \draw_begin:
  \draw_linewidth:n { \l__expl_shuffle_fp }
  \draw_cap_round:
  \draw_join_round:
  \draw_path_moveto:n { 0.0ex , 1.0ex }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { 0.0ex , 0.0ex }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { 1.75ex , 0.0ex }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { 1.75ex , 1.0ex }
  \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
  \draw_path_moveto:n { 0.875ex , 0.0ex }
  \draw_path_lineto:n { 0.875ex , 1.0ex }
  \draw_path_use_clear:n { stroke }
  \draw_end:
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\explshuffle}{}
 {
  \mathrel
   {
    \fp_set:Nn \l__expl_shuffle_fp { 0.08ex }
    \text{$\mspace{1mu}$ \expl_shuffle: $\mspace{1mu}$}
   }
 }
%---------------------------------------------------------
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\[
  A \explshuffle B_{A \explshuffle B_{A \explshuffle B}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have only rotate and reflect the symbol `\exists`...creating a newcommand.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\rexists}{\raisebox{\depth}{\rotatebox{270}{$\exists$}}}

\begin{document}
$A \mathrel{\rexists}B$

\end{document}
```

[image]