# Big shuffle symbol?

Tags: symbols, math-operators

I am looking for a "big" version ([sum-class symbol](http://latex.wikia.com/wiki/Sum-class_symbol)) of the ш symbol (shuffle product).
I only found a [binary version](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/shuffle). Any ideas?

Comment: You could [compose your own operator](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/183988/5764)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just scale it.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

% large ops, copied from shuffle font package
\DeclareFontFamily{U}{bigshuffle}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{bigshuffle}{m}{n}{
  <5-8> s*[1.7] shuffle7
  <8->  s*[1.7] shuffle10
}{}
\DeclareSymbolFont{BigShuffle}{U}{bigshuffle}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol\bigshuffle{\mathop}{BigShuffle}{"001}
\DeclareMathSymbol\bigcshuffle{\mathop}{BigShuffle}{"002}

% binary ops, for comparasion only
\usepackage{shuffle}

\begin{document}

\[
  a\shuffle b, x \cshuffle y
\]

\[
  \bigshuffle_i a_i, \bigcshuffle_{j=1}^n x_j
\]

\end{document}
```