# How to set a newcommand to be incompressible by justification?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I have a command `\newcommand{\shuprod}{\sqcup \hspace{-.137cm} \sqcup \;}` that looks good most of the time (i.e. in big equations), but is sometimes "compressed" when inside text.

[image: inside equation]

[image: inside text]

How do I force it to always be the same size ?

Comment: `\newcommand{\shuprod}{\mathrel{{\sqcup}\mkern-3mu{\sqcup}}}` is possibly a safer definition. TeX scretches some horizontal space so that text fits better on a line. This also happens between the `\sqcup`s. How are you using your command? If the font changes, the value `-.137cm` won't be right anymore.

Comment: Works perfectly thanks ! I was using `-.38em` but tried with `cm` thinking it would fix the length.

Comment: Same symbol as [Latex Math Symbol - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183988/latex-math-symbol/183989#183989). (⧢)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When TeX constructs a line it can scretch some horizontal dimensions, even those between your two `\sqcup`s which both still act as binary symbols.

I propose the following change:

```
\newcommand{\shuprod}{\mathbin{{\sqcup}\mspace{-3mu}{\sqcup}}}
```

- `\mathbin` to have the new construction act as *one* binary symbol.
- `{\sqcup}` to disable the symbol acting as a binary symbol.
- `\mkern-3mu` (or `\mspace{-3mu}` with `amsmath`) instead of `\hspace` to make the spacing dependent of the font size.

This still doesn't solve the spacing when used in a different math-style.
For this, you can use [`\mathchoice`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148740/16595) to specify the space for the different math styles.

```
\newcommand{\shuprod}{\mathbin{{\sqcup}\mathchoice{\mspace{-3mu}}
                                                  {\mspace{-3mu}}
                                                  {\mspace{-3mu}}
                                                  {\mspace{-4mu}}{\sqcup}}}
```

Of course, these values are font-dependent.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\newcommand{\shuprod}{\mathbin{{\sqcup}\mspace{-3mu}{\sqcup}}}
\newcommand{\Shuprod}{\sqcup \hspace{-.137cm} \sqcup \;} % do not use

\newcommand{\shuprod}{\mathbin{{\sqcup}\mathchoice{\mspace{-3mu}}
                                                  {\mspace{-3mu}}
                                                  {\mspace{-3mu}}
                                                  {\mspace{-4mu}}{\sqcup}}}
\begin{document}

\( \displaystyle A \sqcup B \)
\( A \sqcup B \)
\( {}_{A \sqcup B} \)
\( {}_{{}_{A \sqcup B}} \)

\( \displaystyle A \shuprod B \)
\( A \shuprod B \)
\( {}_{A \shuprod B} \)
\( {}_{{}_{A \shuprod B}} \)

Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca $ a \shuprod b $ 
Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca 

Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca $ a \Shuprod b $ 
Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca 

\Huge 
$ a \shuprod b $\par
Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abc $ a \shuprod b $

$ a \Shuprod b $\par
Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abca Abc $ a \Shuprod b $ %‽
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Comment: I believe it should be `\mathbin`.

Answer (score 5):

There is the [`shuffle` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/shuffle) that provides the symbol, but only in bitmap format.

However, since this is a simple symbol like `\sqcup`, it's not difficult to draw it manually.

In the following, the height of the symbol is the same as of `\sqcup`, but the width is not double, because it seems too much.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\shuprod}{\mathbin{\mathpalette\shuprod@\relax}}
\newcommand{\shuprod@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\dimen@}{\shuprod@width{#1}}%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\sqcup$}%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{\wd\z@}%
  \raisebox{0.5\dimen@}{%
    \begin{picture}(1.5,0.805)
    \linethickness{\dimen@}%
    \roundcap\roundjoin
    \polyline(0.12,0.84)(0.12,0)(1.38,0)(1.38,0.84)
    \Line(0.75,0)(0.75,0.84)
    \end{picture}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\shuprod@width}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle \fontdimen8\textfont\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle \fontdimen8\textfont\else
  \ifx#1\scriptstyle 1.1\fontdimen8\scriptfont\else
  1.25\fontdimen8\scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi 3
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

$A\shuprod B$

$\shuprod \scriptstyle \shuprod \scriptscriptstyle \shuprod$

$\sqcup \scriptstyle \sqcup \scriptscriptstyle \sqcup$

\setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}
\fbox{$\sqcup$}\fbox{$\shuprod$}

\end{document}
```

[image]