# Tikz externalize creating pdf with repeated images

Tags: tikz-pgf, externalize

I defined a command `masterTriangle` to put inline a triangle created using the tikz library. I use this command many times in my document, which is actually a big book and thus for which I need to use the `externalize` tikz library. I see some strange behavior, since the produced pdf file has 4 instances of the triangle (the compiled external figure, not document). In my actual document there are more than 200 instances of that triangle after compiling the whole book. Can someone explain why this is happening? This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{scalerel} % assembly operator
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{scalerel}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[prefix=./]

% define custom inline commands
\tikzset{
    masterTriangleImpl/.pic={
        \draw (0,0) -- (1,0) -- (0,1) -- cycle;
    }}
\def\masterTriangle{\scalerel*{\ensuremath{\;\tikzsetnextfilename{masterTriangle}\tikz[x=1em, y=1em, line width=1pt]\pic{masterTriangleImpl};}}{X\rule[-.35ex]{0pt}{1pt}}\xspace}

\begin{document}
This is my \masterTriangle and this is another \masterTriangle.
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE**

Following the suggestion of @Qrrbrbirlbel, I just draw the triangle using the `pic2e` package. This is my solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{xspace}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\masterTriangle}{\ensuremath{\mathbin{\mathpalette\masterTriangle@\relax}}\xspace}
\newcommand{\masterTriangle@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\dimen@}{\masterElement@width{#1}}%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th#1\sqcup$}%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{\wd\z@}%
  \raisebox{0.5\dimen@}{%
    \begin{picture}(1,1)
    \linethickness{\dimen@}%
%    \roundcap\roundjoin
    \polygon(0.05,0.05)(0.95,0.05)(0.05,0.95)
    \end{picture}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\masterElement@width}[1]{%
  \ifx#1\displaystyle \fontdimen8\textfont\else
  \ifx#1\textstyle \fontdimen8\textfont\else
  \ifx#1\scriptstyle 1.1\fontdimen8\scriptfont\else
  1.25\fontdimen8\scriptscriptfont\fi\fi\fi 3
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
This is my \masterTriangle and this is another $\masterTriangle$.
\end{document}
```

which produces the desired outcome without using tikz.

Comment: Did you see the produced pdf? It has 4 triangles in it instead of only 1.

Comment: Ah, yes it does. I see. Without checking the code but I'm sure `\scalerel` first typesets the TikZ picture in a box to find out its size and then it typesets it again resized. The `external` library picks both up and externalizes them both.

Comment: `\tikz[baseline=+0pt, line width=1pt] \draw (0,+-.35ex) -- +({width("X")*1pt},0) -- +(0,{width("X")*1pt}) -- cycle;` gives you almost the same triangle without `scalerel`. Almost because the linewidth *stays* at 1pt.

Comment: Do you mean to write the macro as `\def\masterTriangle{\ensuremath{\;\tikzsetnextfilename{masterTriangle}\tikz[baseline=+0pt, line width=1pt] \draw (0,+-.35ex) -- +({width("X")*1pt},0) -- +(0,{width("X")*1pt}) -- cycle;}}`? That doesn't work for me.

Comment: Yes it's supposed to be mainly used for math mode, although sometimes I use it in text as well, so I use the `\ensuremath` to avoid that error when not using $. Also, AFAIK, the `\xspace` is used for the end of macros right? In any case I'm still trying to figure out why is it that there are so many triangle instances in the produced .pdf. In my main document that number is in the hundreds.

Comment: [tag:xspace] inserts a space unless interpunction follows the macro. It's there to deal with TeX eating spaces after command sequence. Is your triangle an operator or just an ordinary symbol? Since there's nothing mathy inside `\ensuremath` you already can use it in text and math mode without a problem. (Though `width("X")` only picks up the normal upright `X` and not the slanted math mode `X` → `width("$X$")`.) My solution will not scale properly when used in subscripts but that can be fixed.

Comment: The symbol is supposed to work as well in subscripts (I actually mainly use it for inline text as a full-sized symbol and also for subscripts and for integral limits). That's also the reason I need scalerel I guess?

Comment: I just played around with [`\mathchoice`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78872) but that has the annoying [habit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/1223) to just typeset all four variants (but only output one) which creates four pages per usage in math-mode. Let's start from the top: Is there a problem with having the externalized PDF double the pages? You could also just typeset these symbols once for every math style and save them in a savebox and/or in a pdf and just include them?

Comment: If it's just a triangle, it might be faster to just draw it with PGF and forget about externalizing it. If it's that simple, you might be able to just draw it [`pict2e`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/668150).

Comment: I ended up drawing the symbol as you suggested in that post above. Thanks!